# What happens to the imported repository when deleting the original one in github

Tags: github, import, version-control, repository

I imported a repository from my old account in GitHub, now I wonder, what will happen to my new imported repository if I decide to delete the original one on the old account, or delete the account itself? Is there any reflect on the imported repository on the new account, or they become independent after the importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imported said repository by:

- cloning the old one locally
- pushing it to a new empty repo in a new account

Then there would be no special relation between the two repositories, even though they have the same history.
You can delete your old repo and/or account safely: the new repo will not be affected.

Even through https://github.com/new/import, the process should be the same: simple duplication (clone), without any link between the old and new one.
It is a page made to facilitate import of repositories from other sources (GitLab, BitBucket, ...)

Comment: but that is not the case, I import it by `import repository` option in github, he ask me to type the URL of the repository I want to import

Comment: @MohamedSaad I have edited the answer: the gist of it remains the same.